# How do I open this light fitting?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

These fittings don't have any obvious affordance for removing or opening them.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Important question that affects answer: do you want to be able to put this fixture back together afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Try twisting the ring around glass part, or twisting the entire thing.

I suspect it's just the glass bit.

Comment: Since this was brought back to the top after a whole year I assume the OP has figured this out, but I gave this answer an upvote so it can be archived. 

This is correct. Typically these puck lights need a slight twist to remove the lens. Sometimes all you can use is your fingertips and it can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Grab it and twist the hell out of it to the left OR a big hammer.